# Is "after all" necessary in the following paragraph?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

> Of all the people who wanted to join the trip, Anna was the the last I
>   expected would come. We barely knew each other at school **after
>   all,** and I was pretty sure she wasn't interested in me.

Is the **after all** necessary? What's a situation where it's definitely needed?

Comment: Yes, look up "after all" in a dictionary. See also [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

In the quoted text, the idiomatic phrase "after all" means roughly the same thing that the phrase "for one thing" would. The author includes "after all" as a way of emphasizing the progression of his (or her) thought in explaining why Anna's interest in joining the trip came as a surprise. In other words, "after all" serves a stylistic purpose. You could omit it and still convey the essential facts about  how well the narrator and Anna knew each other and what the narrator thought Anna's level of interest in him (or her) was; but you would lose some of the "thinking aloud" tone of the remarks.

The OP's focus on the necessity or non-necessity of "after all" in the quoted text seems a bit odd, considering that so much of the rest of the wording is similarly style-driven. If you just wanted to express the gist of the excerpt, you could do it in a single sentence:

> I was surprised that Anna wanted to join the trip, since we barely knew each other at school and she didn't seem interested in me.

But given that the author wants to draw the reader into the narrator's thinking process, "after all" (or something equivalent to it) is at least as necessary as the language about Anna's being the last of all the people who wanted to join the trip that the narrator expected to come.

Answer (score 1):

> Of all the people who wanted to join the trip, Anna was the the last I
>   expected would come. We barely knew each other at school,
>   and I was pretty sure she wasn't interested in me.

If you check [after all](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/after_all) you'll see that it is not necessary.

I suppose you are the author, you can choose if you want to add it. If you do, probably it would be better to put it at the beginning of the clause: *"After all, we..."*.

As to your second question, it is almost impossible to imagine a sentence in which we cannot dispose of it.